# More pythonic way to find a complementary DNA strand

Tags: python

Here's what I have, but it seems kind of redundant.  Maybe someone more experienced in Python knows of a way to clean this up?  Should be pretty self explanatory what it does.

```
def complementary_strand(self, strand):
        ''' Takes a DNA strand string and finds its opposite base pair match. '''
        strand = strand.upper()
        newstrand = ""
        for i in range(0, len(strand)):
            if strand[i] == "T":
                newstrand += "A"

            if strand[i] == "A":
                newstrand += "T"

            if strand[i] == "G":
                newstrand += "C"

            if strand[i] == "C":
                newstrand += "G"

        return newstrand
```

Comment: Why define an unused self argument?  If this is more of a static method, defining @staticmethod def complimentary_strand(strand) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Another note: it is much faster to put all your new letters in a list and then do `return ''.join(bases_list)`.

Comment: Yet another note: it is simpler and faster to do `for base in strand` and replace your strand[i] with `base`.

Comment: And an additional note: instead of doing 'if... if...', it is simpler and faster to do: 'if... elif... elif...'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way to do it, if the string is long enough:

```
import string

def complementary_strand(self, strand):
    return strand.translate(string.maketrans('TAGCtagc', 'ATCGATCG'))
```

This is making use of the [translate](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate) and [maketrans](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) methods. You can also move the translate table creation outside the function:

```
import string
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.trans = string.maketrans('TAGCtagc', 'ATCGATCG')

def complementary_strand(self, strand):
    return strand.translate(self.trans)
```

Comment: +1 -- I was looking for `string.maketrans`, since `strand.translate` has that interesting 256-character restriction.

Comment: +1 -- translate is fast as greased lightning, and you're using it just right (esp. in the second, class-based version).

Comment: @Alex: You aren't kidding, that's a lot faster than I expected.

Comment: It is str.maketrans now.

Answer (score 6):

Even better would be to craft a generator, instead:

```
TRANS = { "T": "A", "A": "T", "G": "C", "C": "G" }

def complementary_strand(self, strand):
    for base in strand.upper():
        yield TRANS[base]
```

Then you can use it any way you want, and an iterator is more efficient:

```
for base in strand.complementary_strand():
    # Do something
```

Comment: I was going to post something very similar to this, except that I would define the `trans` dict outside that function, because that information is bound to be needed elsewhere and it would be good not to repeat it.

Comment: It was implied, but I made it definite.

Comment: @JedSmith: is this actually faster / more space efficient than Nadia's solution?

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
def complementary_strand(self, strand):
    return strand.upper().translate(maketrans("TAGC", "ATCG"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    # ... original __init__ method, and:
    self.trans = { "T": "A", "A": "T", "G": "C", "C": "G" }

def complementary_strand(self, strand):
    '''Takes a DNA strand string and returns its opposite base pair match.'''
    return ''.join([self.trans[base] for base in strand.upper()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compliment(Nucleotide):
    comp = []
    for i in Nucleotide:
        if i == "T":
            comp.append("A")
        if i == "A":
            comp.append("T")
        if i == "G":
            comp.append("C")
        if i == "C":
            comp.append("G")

    return ''.join(comp)
```