# Use a dictionary to provide the mapping of DNA to RNA bases

Tags: python

I wrote this code in order to answer the topic 8 question 5 in pyschools learning process. The code is working but I believe that there is a more elegant way to take the same result, but as a novice not only in python but also in programming I can't think anything. Can anybody to help?

```
# Use a dictionary to provide the mapping of DNA to RNA bases.
def mRNAtranscription(dna_template):
    dna2rna = { }
    mrna = ''
    l = []
    for base in dna_template: 
        dna2rna =  {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
        mrna = dna2rna.get(base)
        l.append(mrna)
    return ''.join(l)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Biopython](http://biopython.org) project's tutorial, then check out the source of the various classes and methods that match what you're trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738633/more-pythonic-way-to-find-a-complementary-dna-strand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `dna_template` is a string and I think this is the way to go if you do not want to dive in special modules.

```
def func(dna_template):
    dna2rna =  {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
    # take every base and translate it to rna and join all rna-bases to a string
    return ''.join(dna2rna.get(base) for base in dna_template)

func('ATCG')

Out:'UAGC'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not bad but also not terribly idiomatic. A list comprehension is a good way to go:

```
dna2rna = {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
rna = ''.join([ dna2rna[base] for base in dna_template])
```

By the way, as a point of hygiene, try to avoid sticking a definition of a constant (like your `dna2rna`) inside of a loop...it just costs processing time in there!